# Are you sure you want to delete?

Tags: jquery

I just wrote a confirm delete function that requires a class name:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ConfirmDelete').click(function() {
        var question = $(this).attr('title');
        if (question == '') question = 'Delete this record?';
        return confirm(question);
    });
});
```

Usage:

```
<input name="Delete" type="submit" value="Delete" class="ConfirmDelete" title="Delete #UsrName#?" />
```

I'd like to change the selector from .ConfirmDelete to something like:

```
$('input:submit').attr('name','Delete').val('Delete')
```

Meaning:
If a submit button has the name 'Delete' and it's value is 'Delete', then go ahead and assume they want to confirm the delete without requiring them to have a ConfirmDelete class.

Comment: You could use an html5 data tag, data-delete="true", then use jQuery to find them.

Comment: Nah.  Anytime it's a submit button with the name of "delete" with a value of "delete", I want it to confirm "Are you sure" before submitting the form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(':submit[name="Delete"][value="Delete"]').click(function() {
    return window.confirm(this.title || 'Delete this record?');
});
```

Comment: This answer was written in 2010.  I would use $('form').on('click','input:submit[name=Delete][value="Delete"]',function() {}) now.

Comment: As in your Company? Well ok, but that doesn’t necessarily apply to everyone... so it’s not a very helpful addition to the answer IMO.

Answer (score 6):

The following would apply to all present, and future instances of any submit button having both the name and value of "Delete":

```
$(function(){

    $(":submit[name='Delete'][value='Delete']").live("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // remove if not necessary
      // Seriously, delete it.
    });

});
```

Comment: Jonathan, you bring up a good point using the live method.  Back in 2010 that was an excellent point.  Q: Does the "on" method use event delegation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
$('input:submit[name="Delete"][value="Delete"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but if I interpret it correctly, you actually want to know the syntax to select a `input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete"` in jQuery?

If so, here it is:

```
$('input:submit[name="Delete"][value="Delete"]')
```

Comment: A bit vague?  My goodness I don't know how much more I could have put into the question without going on and on!

Comment: The topic title did in no way cover the **actual** problem/question.